# firstRow = rowsResult[0]; solo me devuelve un resultado

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Usando Google Apps Script he intentado crear una herramienta para buscar productos por nombre a través de un formulario.
Mi "base de datos" es un Google Sheet distribuido de la siguiente maneara:

```
+---+---------+------------+
|   |    A    |     B      |
|---|---------|------------|
| 1 | userID1 | someValue1 |
|---|---------|------------|
| 2 | userID2 | someValue2 |
|---|---------|------------|
| 3 | userID3 | someValue3 |
|---|---------|------------|
| 4 | userID4 | someValue4 |
```

Actualmente si busco un campo que contiene texto de la columna A, me muestra el campo de la columna B de esa misma fila. Por ejemplo, si busco "user" la herramienta me devolverá someValue1. Necesitaría que funcione de la siguiente manera:
si busco "user" me devuelva una lista como la siguiente, es decir, todos los campos donde
existe la palabra user:

> ```
>     | userID1 | someValue1 |
>     | userID2 | someValue2 |
>     | userID3 | someValue3 |
>     | userID4 | someValue4 |
> ```

```
         si busco "userID1" me devuelva lo siguiente, ya que el campo buscado es  exactamente igual a 
         uno existente en la columna A del google sheet.
```

> ```
>    | userID1 | someValue1 |
> ```

Adjunto el código utilizado:

```
    /**
 * Busca en la hoja de calculos los datos del usuario
 * @param userId ID del usuario que queremos buscar
 */
function searchData(userId) {
  // Obtiene la hoja de calculos
  var sheet = getSpreadSheet(myGoogleSheetURL, myGoogleSheetName);

  // Recorre todas las filas buscando la coincidencia del userID con el valor
  // de la columna 0
  var rowsResult = sheet
  .getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn())
  .getValues()
  .filter(function (row) {
    if (row[0].toString().indexOf(userId) === -1) {return false;} else {return true;}
    });

  // Obtiene el resultado
  var firstRow = rowsResult[0];

  // Parsea cada uno de los campos
  var user = {
    id: firstRow[0],
    email: firstRow[1],
  };

  // Serializa el OBJ para enviar la respuesta al frontend
  var result = JSON.stringify(user);
  return result;
}
```

¿Podrían ayudarme a encointrar la solución, por favor? Entiendo que tendré que introducir algún `for` pero la verdad que no sé como hacerlo.
Gracias de antemano

---

Tras modificar el código como comenta @Pablo Lozano en su respuesta ahora siempre obtengo el valor "undefined". Adjunto como ha quedado tanto el codigo del archivo como del formulario:

```
    function searchData(userId) {
  // Obtiene la hoja de calculos
  var sheet = getSpreadSheet(myGoogleSheetURL, myGoogleSheetName);

  // Recorre todas las filas buscando la coincidencia del userID con el valor
  // de la columna 0
  var rowsResult = sheet
  .getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn())
  .getValues()
  .filter(function (row) {
    if (row[0].toString().indexOf(userId) === -1) {return false;} else {return true;}
    })
  .map(function (row) {
    return {id: row[0], email: row[1]};
    });
  return JSON.stringify(rowsResult);
  }
```

FORMULARIO

```
    // Función que se ejecuta cuando la busqueda ocurre con exito
function onSuccess(response) {
  // Parsea la respuesta
  var user = JSON.parse(response);

  // Carga el campo email de la respuesta en el div
  document.getElementById("divResponse").innerHTML = user.email;

  // Habilita el campo y boton
  enableInputs();
}

// Función que se ejecuta cuando la busqueda ocurre con ERROR
function onFailure() {
  // Pone mensaje en div
  document.getElementById("divResponse").innerHTML = "Fabric not found";
  enableInputs();
}
```

---

SOLUCIÓN ENCONTRADA

El problema era en que en el formulario, solo le estaba pasando el campo email en lugar del resto. Tras pasarle el resto ya funciona ok.

Gracias!

Comment: La respuesta de Pablo es correcta. Tal vez no esta coincidiendo el valor que buscas. Podes probar con el metodo **.toLowerCase()**    if ( row[0].toString().toLowerCase().indexOf( userId.toString().toLowerCase() ) === -1 ) { return false;} else {return true;}

Comment: @PatrickArguello Sigue sin funcionar, creo que el problema no está en el IF sino en el .map y en el posterior return. Tengo la sensación de que no le estamos devolviendo el valor de ese .map al return final, pero la verdad que lo he intentado modificar y no encuentro la solución.

Comment: ¡Hola! Por favor, escribí tu solución (detallada) como respuesta, en lugar de editar la pregunta para incluirla.

Answer (score 3):

La variable `rowsResult` tiene todos las filas que cumplen el filtro, pero tú te estás quedando sólo con una (la primera):

```
// Obtiene el resultado
var firstRow = rowsResult[0];
```

La solución es quedarte con todo:

```
...
var rowsResult = sheet
  .getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn())
  .getValues()
  .filter(function (row) {
    if (row[0].toString().indexOf(userId) === -1) {return false;} else {return true;}
    })
  .map(function (row) {
    return {id: row[0], email: row[1]};
    });

return JSON.stringify(rowsResult);
```

Usando map transformamos cada fila en un objeto en el formato que quieres, con lo que tenemos al final un array de objetos con `id` y `email` como propiedades.

Comment: Supongo que querías decir "con id y `email`" como propieades.

Comment: Bien visto, arreglado!

Comment: Gracias @PabloLozano acabo de actualizar mi pregunta con el resultado obtenido tras realizar tu modificación

Answer (score 1):

Solución encontrada, el FORMULARIO estaba recibiendo mal la información.
Adjunto el código ya actualizado, creé una función para crear una tabla con los resultados:

```js
function creartabla(datos){
    clearDiv();
    
  //  window.alert(datos.length);
    
    if (datos.length == 0) 
    {document.getElementById("divResponse").innerHTML = "FABRIC NOT FOUND";}
    else
    {
    
    // Obtener la referencia del elemento body
    var body = document.getElementById("divResponse");
   
    
    // Crea un elemento <table> y un elemento <tbody>
    var tabla   = document.createElement("table");
   // table.style.textAlign = 'center';
    var tblBody = document.createElement("tbody");
    
    //Cabeceras
    var fila = document.createElement("tr");
    
    //codigo  
    var celda = document.createElement("td");
    var textoCelda = document.createTextNode("CODE");
    celda.appendChild(textoCelda);
    fila.appendChild(celda);
    
    //nombre
    celda = document.createElement("td");
    textoCelda = document.createTextNode("NAME");
    celda.appendChild(textoCelda);
    fila.appendChild(celda);
    
    //stock
    celda = document.createElement("td");
    textoCelda = document.createTextNode("STOCK");
    celda.appendChild(textoCelda);
    fila.appendChild(celda);
    
    tblBody.appendChild(fila);
    
    // Crea las celdas
    for (var f = 0; f < datos.length; f++) {
    // Crea las filas de la tabla
    var fila = document.createElement("tr");
    
    //codigo
    var celda = document.createElement("td");
    var textoCelda = document.createTextNode(datos[f].codigo);
    celda.appendChild(textoCelda);
    fila.appendChild(celda);
    
    //nombre
    celda = document.createElement("td");
    textoCelda = document.createTextNode(datos[f].nombre);
    celda.appendChild(textoCelda);
    fila.appendChild(celda);
    
    //stock
    celda = document.createElement("td");
    textoCelda = document.createTextNode(datos[f].stock);
    celda.appendChild(textoCelda);
    fila.appendChild(celda);
    
   
    
    // agrega la fila al final de la tabla (al final del elemento tblbody)
    tblBody.appendChild(fila);
    }
    
    // posiciona el <tbody> debajo del elemento <table>
    tabla.appendChild(tblBody);
    // appends <table> into <body>
    body.appendChild(tabla);
    // modifica el atributo "border" de la tabla y lo fija a "2";
    tabla.setAttribute("border", "2");
    tabla.setAttribute("align", "center");
    
    }
    }
```